# Vue-bootstrap how to achieve smooth working my popover

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, popover, bootstrap-vue

I have a simple Vue app, which has many cards, when I mouse over a card it shows a button, then when I mouse over the button it shows popover, but my popover works not as I expected. It blinks when I try to reach it's content and doesn't hide at mouse leave popover.

template

```
<div id="app">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <b-card-group>
      <b-card
        v-for="(card, index) in cards"
        :key="card.id"
        :id="card.id"
        v-on:mouseover="card.show_menu = true"
        v-on:mouseleave="card.show_menu = false"
        bg-variant="light"
        class="text-center m-1 cards"
      >
        <b-card-text id="note-text">{{card.text}}</b-card-text>
        <hr />
        <div v-if="!card.show_menu">
          <b-card-text id="note-text" class="small muted-text m-0 p-0">
          <p>Super informal text here </p>
          <p>Super informal text here </p>
          </b-card-text>
        </div>
        <div v-else>
          <div>
            <img
              src="https://i7.pngguru.com/preview/369/878/399/computer-icons-plus-sign-clip-    art-plus-sign-thumbnail.jpg"
              class="m-2"
              width="24"
              height="24"
              alt
              :id="'image_id_' + card.id"
              v-on:mouseover="card.show_pop = true"
            />

            <b-popover
              :show.sync="card.show_pop"
              :target="'image_id_' + card.id"
              placement="bottom"
              v-on:mouseleave="note.show_pop = false"
            >
              <p>Super popover data!</p>
            </b-popover>
          </div>
        </div>
      </b-card>
     </b-card-group>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

js

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    cards: [
      {id: 1, text: 'some text goes here', show_menu: false, show_pop: false},
      {id: 2, text: 'some text goes here', show_menu: false, show_pop: false},
    ]
  }
})
```

Can somebody explain how to fix that issue https://jsfiddle.net/nashgc/by2fxm4z/23/

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `mouseover` and `mouseleave` events, and instead use the `hover` trigger on your popover instead.
You will also need to set a container on your popover, to your card. Since by default it's appended to `body`, meaning your card's mouseover event wont work anymore, which is why it's losing when you hover it.

```html
<img
  src="https://i7.pngguru.com/preview/369/878/399/computer-icons-plus-sign-clip-art-plus-sign-thumbnail.jpg"
  class="m-2"
  width="24"
  height="24"
  alt
  :id="'image_id_' + card.id"
/>

<b-popover
  :target="'image_id_' + card.id"
  triggers="hover"
  :container="`#${card.id}`"
  placement="bottom"
>
  <p>Super popover data!</p>
</b-popover>
```

*Sidenote: I don't believe mouseover/mouseevent (along with the hover trigger on popover) are accessible events on mobile devices, along with keyboard only users. So your current design might not be useable for multiple users.*

Comment: I did as you say, it works better, but it blinks anyway when I try to move my mouse pointer from image to popover. As i mention via Vue devtool, my popover element delete and append on this moment. any suggestions?